# my code creates undifined behaviour when I remove cout<<endl;

Tags: c++11, binary-search-tree

this is my header

```
/**
* Title: Trees
* Description: NgramTree class to count and store ngrams in a given string
*/

#ifndef NGRAMTREE_H
#define NGRAMTREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef string TreeItemType;
struct TreeNode {

    TreeItemType item;
    TreeNode *leftChildPtr, *rightChildPtr;
    int count;

};

// NgramTree.h
class NgramTree { 
    
public:

    NgramTree();

    ~NgramTree();

    void addNgram( string ngram ); 
    
    
    int getTotalNgramCount(); 
    
    bool isComplete();
    
    bool isFull();

    bool isFull(TreeNode* curr);
    
    void generateTree( string fileName, int n );

    ostream& print_recursive( ostream &out, TreeNode *curr );

    ostream& print( ostream &out );



private:
// ...
    TreeNode *root;
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, NgramTree &tree );

    void destroyTree(TreeNode *& treePtr);

    int getTotalNgramCount(TreeNode *node); 


};

#endif
```

this is the cpp

```
/**
* Title: Trees
* Assignment: 2
* Description: implementation of NgramTree class
*/

#include "NgramTree.h"

//empty constructor
NgramTree::NgramTree():root(NULL){};

//destructor
NgramTree::~NgramTree(){
    destroyTree(root);
}

bool NgramTree::isFull(){
    return isFull(root);
}

bool NgramTree::isFull(TreeNode* curr){

    if(curr->leftChildPtr != NULL && curr->rightChildPtr != NULL ){

        return isFull(curr->leftChildPtr) && isFull(curr->rightChildPtr);
    }

    // on leaf node
    else if( curr->leftChildPtr == NULL && curr->rightChildPtr == NULL  ){
        return true;
    }

    
    else if( curr == NULL ){
        return true;
    }

    //ever other condition
    return false;
}

void NgramTree::addNgram( string ngram ){

    
    if(root == NULL){
        cout<<endl;
        TreeNode *tmp = new TreeNode;
        tmp->item = ngram;
        tmp->count = 1;
        root = tmp;
        return;
    }

    for( TreeNode *curr = root; curr != NULL; ){

        if( ngram.compare(curr->item) == 0){

            curr->count++;
            return;
        }
        else if( ngram.compare(curr->item) < 0 ){

            // if the node is leaf or node has just right child we have to add ngram to the leftChildPtr
            if( curr->leftChildPtr == NULL ){
                TreeNode *tmp = new TreeNode;
                tmp->item = ngram;
                tmp->count = 1;
                tmp->leftChildPtr = NULL;
                tmp->rightChildPtr = NULL;
                curr->leftChildPtr = tmp;
                return;
            }
            else{
                curr = curr->leftChildPtr;
            } 
        }

        else if( ngram.compare(curr->item) > 0 ){
            
            // if the node is leaf or node has just left child we have to add ngram to //the leftChildPtr
            if( curr->rightChildPtr == NULL ){
                TreeNode *tmp = new TreeNode;
                tmp->item = ngram;
                tmp->count = 1;
                tmp->leftChildPtr = NULL;
                tmp->rightChildPtr = NULL;
                curr->rightChildPtr = tmp;
                return;
            }
            else{
                curr = curr->rightChildPtr;
            } 

        }
    }
}

void NgramTree::generateTree( string fileName, int n ){

    string s;
    s = "";

    //first loop to find words
    for(size_t i = 0; i < fileName.length(); ++i){
        
        if(fileName[i] != ' '){
            
            s += fileName[i];
        }

        //after a word end there is a  ' ' 
        if(fileName[i] == ' ' || i == fileName.length()-1  ){
            

            for(size_t j = 0; j <= s.length() - n; ++j ){

                addNgram( s.substr(j,n) );

            }
            s = "";


        }

        

    }
}

int NgramTree::getTotalNgramCount(){

    return getTotalNgramCount(root);
}

int NgramTree::getTotalNgramCount(TreeNode *node){

    if( node != NULL){ 

        // total count is node->count + count(leftSubTree) + count(rightSubTree)
        return node->count 
            + getTotalNgramCount(node->leftChildPtr) 
                + getTotalNgramCount(node->rightChildPtr);
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void NgramTree::destroyTree(TreeNode *&treePtr){

        if (treePtr != NULL){
            destroyTree(treePtr->leftChildPtr);
            destroyTree(treePtr->rightChildPtr);
            delete treePtr;
            treePtr = NULL;
        }
}

ostream& NgramTree::print_recursive( ostream &out, TreeNode *curr ) {

    if( curr == NULL ) return out;

    out<<endl;

    out<<"item= "<<curr->item<<", frequency= "<<curr->count;

    print_recursive(out, curr->leftChildPtr);
    return print_recursive(out, curr->rightChildPtr);

}

ostream& NgramTree::print( ostream &out ){

    TreeNode *tmp = root;
    return print_recursive(out, tmp);
    
}

ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, NgramTree &tree ){

    return tree.print(out);

}

int main(){

    NgramTree t;

    string s1 = "berkan naber";
    int n1 = 3;

    t.generateTree(s1, n1);

    cout<<t.getTotalNgramCount();

    cout<<t<<endl;



    return 0;

}
```

when I remove `cout<<endl` from `void NgramTree::addNgram( string ngram )` method I get undifined behaviour. I removed it and added in different line and it worked again. I also added it before the if statement and it worked again. What cout<<endl might change in method is it releated to function call stack may be? I am not even sure that the problem comes from this method? I am open to solutions that offering somthing to put instead of `cout<<endl;` which doesn't affect the terminal output unlike cout<<endl.

Comment: `TreeNode` has no constructor so the pointers in it are left uninitialized. Adding a constructor `TreeNode() : leftChildPtr(nullptr), rightChildPtr(nullptr) {}` resolves the crash for me.

Comment: Yes. you are right the problem is that leftChildPtr and rightChildPtr are not initilized but cout<<endl; fixes the problem?

Comment: "fixes" is a strong word. It may rearrange the stack or memory such that you get lucky and this one case works, but doesn't treat the root cause of the problem. In Visual Studio where uninitialized variables are filled with specific debug values it crashes with or without the `cout` line.